# How to copy files from Raspberry Pi to Mounted NAS via Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, copy, nas

I have a camera module connected to my Raspberry Pi and wanted to save the pictures directly on my NAS.
I'm using the picamera library to Control the camera. The camera is working and I'm able to save the picture directly on the Pi. However, if I want to save them on the mounted NAS, it does not work.
I've tried to save the pictures at first local on my Pi and then move them via os.move or shutil.move. However it did not work. Also shutil.copy is not working. 
I can create .txt-files and folders on the NAS via python but copying files does not work.

As an example my code looks like:

```
tempPath = '/home/pi/Desktop/test.jpg' #local directory
destinationPath = '/home/pi/myNAS/test.jpg' #mounted NAS

camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(5)
camera.capture(tempPath)
camera.stop_preview()
shutil.move(tempPath,destinationPath)
```

Comment: I solved this problem with os.system('cp ' + tempPath + ' ' + '/home/pi/myNAS/'). Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any shutil import in your code. Did you import the shutil module ?

```
import shutil
```

Also, what kind of error did you get when you executed the code ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I imported all necessary libraries (picamera, os and shutil) in the first lines of my code. I just forgot to copy them, sorry. I don't remember the error code of os.move() but I found out that os.move() can't move files on different drives. There was no error when I was using shutil.move(). Howver there were no files visible. After a while I had to restart my raspberry and suddenly all files where on the NAS.